# Jupyter Notebook Python Version Inconsistent in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions

I created a conda environment ('pytorch': conda) with python version 3.9.6 and tried to use it in VS code. However, when I run it in VS code with the Jupyter extension, the python version in the interactive window became 3.9.1 (this is the virtual environment I used in the other project), the screenshot is shown as below:

```
Started 'Python 3.9.6 64-bit ('pytorch': conda)' kernel  
Python 3.9.1 (default, Dec 11 2020, 06:28:49)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information  
IPython 7.25.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

I am wondering some of the settings in VS code messed up. How to fix it and make the jupyter works correctly in this environment?

Answer (score 0):

The stuff after the `Started`, just the name of the environment. Can you try to activate the environment of `pytorch`, and then check the python version of it with the command of `python --version`?

You can specify the python version when you create the conda virtual environment like this:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.6
```